# Android consuming JAX WS

Tags: android, web-services

Why is it not possible to utilize the wsdl artifacts you get from wsimport to create a client on the android ?

Answer (score 3):

Android Java Machine doesn't implement JAX-WS specification.
You need to use some pure mechanism like HttpClient (org.apache.http.client.HttpClient) and some XML serialization tools like http://simple.sourceforge.net - unless You are hardcore ;)
ITC